# Why are my React Native View heights inconsistent?

Tags: react-native

I have the following code:

```js
  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.dashboardListItemContainer}>
        <View style={styles.listItemBorder} />
      </View >
    </>
  )
```

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  dashboardListItemContainer: {
    minHeight: 73,
    backgroundColor: COL_DARK_BG,
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
  },
  listItemBorder: {
    minHeight: 0.5,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  }
});
```

Which produces the following result:

[image]

My question is, why are the lines inconsistently bright / appear to be different heights?
Also when I change `column` to `row` here: `flexDirection: "row",` the line disappears completely. I can't tell if this is a bug or there are errors in my code?

TIA.

#### Update:

I cannot solve this problem on any device, and I've tried different methods for determining the height.

`borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,` looks like this:

[image]

You can see in the above picture some lines do not even show up.

`borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth * 2,` looks like this:

[image]

And `height: 0.5,` looks like this on a white background:

[image]

The problem is consistent across devices, it is at the edge of an item in a `<FlatList>`.

Comment: can you provide expo snack demo so we can reproduce this problem and give the correct answer

Answer (score 4):

Android Emulator has less resolution, try on a real device, sometimes i have the same error, and when I run on a real device it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

We can use flex value.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, FlatList } from "react-native";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}
        extraData={[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}
        horizontal={false}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
          return (
            <View style={styles.dashboardListItemContainer}>
              <View style={styles.listItemBorder} />
            </View>
          );
        }}
        key={({ item, index }) => index}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  dashboardListItemContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    display: "flex",
    flex: 1,
    minHeight: 73,
    flexDirection: "column"
  },
  listItemBorder: {
    minHeight: 0.5,
    backgroundColor: "yellow"
  }
});
```

[image: This how it will display on screen]